# keep the shell script running even after moving to some other shell using script command without logging out from any terminal

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, sh, csh

I have a script with one of its command let say "cmd" this cmd will move the user from the shell to some other server/shell , now when I run this script after executing "cmd" the shell gets changed (normal behaviour) but the commands following the "cmd" will not run and when I logout from the new terminal to come back to original one then only that commands execute on their own .

Is there any way so that the remaining will execute on the new terminal ?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Maybe you could sketch some of the code you already have, so that we have something concrete to discuss?

Comment: 1. some commands ....... 
4. qrsh -P ilight  # command to open a new session on some server
5 .setenv display ####


now I want to set this display on the session newly opened from qrsh command ...

hope now its clear ..

Answer (score -1):

I'm assuming your "cmd" is ssh opening a session on another server. If thats the case you can instruct ssh to run a command once the session is open: ssh user@server.com your_command_here

Comment: exactly the cmd is opening a new session on some server but how to instruct it that commands following it have to be executed in the new session/terminal ?

Comment: ssh user@server.com your_command_here

Comment: if I don't know the server/host name in which my new session will get open then ?